# How to override ctrl-f in safari

Tags: javascript, gwt, safari

Is there any way to override the behaviour of the CTRL+F in Safari browser by changing the focus on the browser finder to focus on my own text box? The following GWT snippet code:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {

    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONKEYDOWN:
                NativeEvent nEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
                if (nEvent.getCtrlKey() && nEvent.getKeyCode() == 'F') {
             focusOnMyTextBox();    
                     nEvent.preventDefault();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

allows me to do the redirection in Firefox and Chrome browsers. However, in Safari the browser finder gets the focus. Any GWT or Javascript tip about this ?

Answer (score 3):

I think this [blogpost](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/how-script-kiddies-can-hijack-your-browser-to-steal-your-password/) is very related: [How script kiddies can hijack your browser to steal your password](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/how-script-kiddies-can-hijack-your-browser-to-steal-your-password/). Relevant code part:

```
 $(window).keydown(function(evt){  
       if((evt.which == "70" && ( evt.metaKey || evt.ctrlKey ))){  
            evt.preventDefault(); 
            /* display fake search */
       }  
  });
```

Further resources: http://h43z.blogspot.de/2012/11/whats-real-and-whats-not.html, http://labs.neohapsis.com/2012/11/14/browser-event-hijacking/

Demos can be found [here](http://h43z.koding.com/blog/leaked.html) and [there](http://boomer.neohapsis.com/searchbox/index.html). Tested both of them in Safari and they do work.

As I don't know much about GWT I'm not sure if this is correct, but here is my GWT try

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {

    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONKEYDOWN:
                NativeEvent nEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
                if((nEvent.which == "70" && ( nEvent.metaKey || nEvent.ctrlKey ))){  
                    nEvent.preventDefault(); 
                    focusOnMyTextBox();   
                }  
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to solve it with javascript:

Add an event listener

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown, false );
```

if you want to remove it later:

```
document.removeEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown, false );
```

The Event-Function:

```
function onDocumentKeyDown( evt ) {

    if(evt.keyCode == "70" &&  evt.ctrlKey ) {
                ...
    }


}
```